# How to install CKEditor 5 autosave plugin?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, ckeditor

I need to integrate the CKEditor 5 autosave plugin. At the moment, I have included the CKEditor like the following.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/25.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js">
</script>
```

However, it doesn't find the autosave plugin, so I suppose I need to install the CKEditor and the plugin on my website to run that.

The problem is that in the CKEditor documentation, the installation is described only with npm. So I don't know how to install the plugin without npm. In CKEditor 4, I needed only to paste the plugin in the plugins folder, and I think that was everything.

My website is developed with the Laravel framework using Laravel Boilerplate. There I have a webpack.mix.js file with a configuration of some npm packages. Unfortunately, I was not able to include the CKEditor and the Autosave plugin and to run that.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('public')
    .setResourceRoot('../') // Turns assets paths in css relative to css file
    .sass('resources/sass/frontend/theme.scss', 'css/frontend/frontend.css')
    .sass('resources/sass/backend/app.scss', 'css/backend/backend.css')
    .js('resources/js/frontend/app.js', 'js/mix/frontend.js')
    .js('resources/js/backend/app.js', 'js/mix/backend.js')
    .extract([
        'alpinejs',
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        'popper.js',
        'axios',
        'sweetalert2',
        'lodash'
    ])
    .sourceMaps();

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
} else {
    // Uses inline source-maps on development
    mix.webpackConfig({
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });
}
```

I only need CKEditor on the front end for the moment. I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me how to integrate it with or without npm.

Answer (score -1):

To install CKEditor 5 using npm try the [@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic) package.

```
npm install --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

Also, you need jQuery as well.

```
npm install --save-dev jquery
```

In bootstrap.js...

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Compile your assets.

```
npm run prod
```

Here's a Blade example.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CKEditor 5 Laravel 8 Example</title>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body class="antialiased">
<div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen pt-8">
    <div id="editor">
        <p>This is some sample content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error.stack);
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as the Autosave plugin, I assume you would need a database, so I didn't attempt that part. But to start, you can install it this way...

```
npm install --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-autosave
```

From there, consult the [Autosave plugin documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html#autosave-feature).